# How do I replace the domain name in a Apache Rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect a URL domain.com to domain.net in a Rewrite rule. I originally used redirect, but it lost the POST variables I was sending. Will a Rewrite carry them over and what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

This should resolve your problem:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thenewdomain.net$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When I'm using this I get two slashes inside the redirected URL. Like `...thenewdomain.net//login`. Because `$1` is `/login` and the new domain also has a slash at the end. I have to use either `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.thenewdomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]` to exclude the leading slash from `$1`, or `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.thenewdomain.net$1 [R=301,L]`. The first one looks nicer but the second one is more fail-save I guess.

Comment: A small, but essential detail.
This will not work: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$[OR]`. You need to add a space:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [OR]`

Comment: You should not use `[R=301]` in `mod_rewrite` examples because if someone simply copy and execute your code once forgetting to change `http://www.thenewdomain.net/` it will be cached in their browser and there is no simple way for him to fix this until a full browser cache reset with some tools. so I advise to change it to `[R=302]` to prevent further debugging troubles for questioners.