# Two domains on same webspace but different content / language by htaccess and GET parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-parameters

I need a rewrite rule or some other solution for accessing pages like

```
www.domain.com/feature.php?lang=de
```

from

```
www.domain.de/feature.php
```

which lies at the same webspace as

```
www.domain.com.
```

From the beginning:

I have a domain

```
www.domain.com
```

with multi language content which is triggered by a language GET parameter.

For instance:

```
www.domain.com/features.php?lang=fr
```

will load the french content from the database, whereas

```
www.domain.com/features.php
```

displays the default English content.

For SEO friendly clean urls I created the following universal htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*).php /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will make urls like

```
www.domain.com/features.php?lang=fr
```

be accessible from the SEO friendly version:

```
www.domain.com/fr/features.php
```

Also other languages like

```
www.domain.com/features.php?lang=it
```

are covered by this and can be accessed by the clean url

```
www.domain.com/it/features.php
```

What I need is a solution for the special case for the German language, because for the German language I have a dedicated domain called domain.de. So it should not be accessible by a path-url like

```
www.domain.com/de/features.php
```

as the other languages, but instead from

```
www.domain.de/features.php
```

I probably have to point the domain target of domain.de to the same webspace as domain.com, since they share the same php files, stylesheets and images.

I don't know how to edit the htaccess file to cover the .de domain as well.

Please consider, that in addition to the hidden lang parameter, there are some pages, which need to pass some GET parameters too. They don't need to be hidden. They just need to be passed. So for instance

```
www.domain.com/features.php?lang=de&a=1&b=2
```

should be accessible from

```
www.domain.de/features.php?a=1&b=2
```

My current htaccess RewriteRule already covers the additional parameters for the .com/x/ domain by [L,QSA] at the end. But I don't know how to set it up to cover access from the .de domain, including the ocationally occuring GET parameters.

It should be a universal solution. So I should not have to enter a line for every of my php files, but instead it should cover all php filenames, as the already existing RewriteRule from above already does for the .com domain.

Thanks.

Comment: This should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7101306/9421134

Comment: @CodiMech25 hmm not really, since my case a little more complex. Or I am too dumb to put it together.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this should give you at least the starting point:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.de$[OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.de$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/de/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(.*).php /$2.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```